# Echo DNS and Alternative DNS using command line/ batch

Tags: loops, for-loop, batch-file, cmd, ipconfig

I have been using a `for loop` with `findstr` to `echo` specific lines from `ipconfig/all`.  For example

`for /f "tokens=*" %a in ('ipconfig/all ^| findstr "#DNS Servers"') do (echo %a)` [double percentage sign to use within batch file]

This will echo out the `DNS Servers line` but how to get the Alternate address that is beneath that in `ipconfig/all`
There nothing in that line to `findstr` to help isolate it.  Is there a way to do this?

Here is the relevant ipconfig/all output.  I am looking for `YYYY`

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : XXXX
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : XXXX
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : XXXX

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : Yes
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Intel 
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : XXXX(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : XXXX
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX
                                       YYYY  
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled
```

I want to try this in batch because it is to use at the end of anther batch program.

Comment: It may be a simple case of using a more specific `findstr` string. How about you provide the output of `IPConfig /All`, exactly as it is output, _(it may be simpler to use `ipconfig /all > output.log` then open `output.log` in notepad, `notepad output.log`, select its content, CTRL-A, copy it, CTRL-C, and paste it into to your question, CTRL-V, formatting it as code, in order to maintain its structure etc.)_.

Comment: `reg query "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Tcpip\Parameters" -v *NameServer`

Comment: Clearly your question code is incorrect then! There is no line which contains the string `#DNS Servers`, and therefore no lines will be returned as `%a`!

Comment: `ipconfig/all` is an invalid argument string, but works because of `cmd.exe` is friendly to users like you and makes several approaches to find out which executable or script to run and by chance finds really `%SystemRoot%\System32\ipconfig.exe` (argument 0 with full qualified file name (drive + path + name + extension) instead of just file name) and runs it with parameter `/all` (argument 1). There should be always a space between command or file name of an executable or script (argument 0) and its parameters (arguments 1 ... n).

Comment: The search string `"#DNS Servers"` is definitely wrong. __FINDSTR__ interprets a space character as __OR__ on specifying the search string with just `"..."`. So `findstr "#DNS Servers"` searches __case-sensitive__ for lines containing either `#DNS` __OR__ `Servers`. It outputs the line `DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : XXXX` as it contains the word `Servers`. You have to use `%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /C:"DNS Servers"` to search for lines containing __case-sensitive__ the __literal__ string `DNS Servers`. I recommend to insert after `findstr.exe` the parameters `/I` and `/L`.

Comment: Open a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/), run `findstr /?` and read the output help for more information about `/I` and `/L` and `/C:`. It is possible to specify multiple `/C:"..."` arguments to search for lines containing any of the specified search strings. For completeness the usage of option `/R` in combination of one or more `/C:"..."` makes it possible to search with one or more regular expression strings on which the space character is interpreted as literal character while usage of `/L` with `"word1 word2 word3"` results in searching literally for one of the words.

Comment: Sorry, now I understand why ```#DNS``` was limiting my output to the line I wanted, it was ignoring it and only using ```Servers```.  Thank you for advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's surprisingly easy in your case:

```
ipconfig /all |findstr /bc:"   DNS-Server" /c:"       "
```

Note: if you have more than one network adapter, you get the DNS-Server(s) (both IPv4 and IPv6) of all of them without any hint, which belongs to which.

Note: the output of `ipconfig` is language-dependent. You probably have to adapt the string `DNS-Server` to your actual output.

If you want the "alternative" DNS-Server only:

```
ipconfig /all |findstr /bc:"       "
```

(`There nothing in that line to findstr to help isolate it.`: yes, there is. It's the only line(s) that starts with more than three spaces. `findstr /b` matches pattern if at the **b**eginning of a line)

Comment: I didn't realise you could search for spaces.  I got confused by ```for loops``` and ```delims``` and thought it was character separated by space (facepalm).  This will also list all the alternative DNS servers if there are many, which is what I wanted.  For this to work for me, the hyphen needed to be removed from ```DNS-Servers```.  Not sure if you need to edit to mark as answer?

Comment: The output of `ipconfig` is language-dependent. In German, it's `DNS-Server`. Adapt it to your actual output (language)